How to solve image captcha?
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = "https://2captcha.com/demo/normal"
driver.get(url)

cap_img = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '_2hXzbgz7SSP0DXCyvKWcha')
cap_img.screenshot('cap.png')


api_key = os.getenv('APIKEY_2CAPTCHA', 'API_KEY')
solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)

try:
    result = solver.normal('cap.png')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

else:
    print('solved: ' + str(result))

error:
'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'normal'
I tried to get image captcha but it give me error.
Can anyone solve this problem?

Does this answer your question? AttributeError: 'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'recaptcha'
